# "FUN" is missing, with no default

Tags: r

I'm learning R and I have a problem:

```
AP <- AirPassengers
plot.ts(AP)
summary(AP) 
plot.ts(AP, main = "Liczba pasażerów amerykańskich linii lotniczych", xlab = "Rok", ylab = "Liczba")

AP.qtr <- aggregate(AP, nfrequency=4)
```

and get an error:

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: Try `aggregate(AP, nfrequency=4, FUN = sum)`

Comment: Unless you want the average, then use `FUN = mean`, or the min, max, median, ...

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Phil and @Gregor `aggregate` need a summary function to aggregate the grouped data. Take a look at `?aggregate`, you will see that aggregate

> Splits the data into subsets, computes summary statistics for each, and returns the result in a convenient form.

the summary statistics are computed according to the `FUN` argument that is :

> a function to compute the summary statistics which can be applied to all data subsets.

For example, if you want to compute the average annual approval ratings for American presidents in the `presidents` time series dataset  you can use `aggregate` like this:

```
aggregate(presidents, nfrequency = 1, FUN = mean)
```